# Cant remove objects using Three.JS

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I'm using Three.JS to make a plane and put some boxes over it
I need remove all boxes sometimes. So I'm trying to do it with the following code:

```
for ( i = 0; i < scene.children.length; i ++ ) {
    var object = scene.children[ i ];
    if ( object != plane && object != camera) {
        scene.remove(object);
    }
}
```

/*This kill each object that is not the plane or the camera ;-)*/

It deletes some boxes, but not all of them =(
How can I delete all boxes?
Greetings, José

Comment: you should not call your var object. that is a reserved keyword for the  actual definition of object.

Comment: object should be fine, Object is reserved (with capital o)

Comment: that's not the problem... =(. @ama2 is right

Comment: Regardless, @FlavorScape is right in that you shouldn't leave case-sensitivity to chance. Just name it something else *anyway*.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to go back to front, not front to back, when removing array objects like this.

```
var obj, i;
for ( i = scene.children.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i -- ) {
    obj = scene.children[ i ];
    if ( obj !== plane && obj !== camera) {
        scene.remove(obj);
    }
}
```

What is happening is when one removes a node, all the ones after it shift. Let's say you remove scene.children[0]: children[1] will become the new 0, 2 will become 1, etc.
When going from 0 to array.length, the for loop has already moved on and is skipping 1 node for every one you delete.

As an additional plus, this should go slightly faster, especially if you have many objects, since scene.children.length is only gotten once, instead of every loop.

Comment: You got it! Thanks @Crazycatz !!!  =D  =D     =D      =D      =D                               =D                                                                                           =D

Answer (score 4):

@Crazycatz answer is correct of course but now we are in 2016 and instead of manual iteration we can just call `.slice()` and iterate over array copy:

```
scene.children.slice().forEach(obj => scene.remove(obj))
```

or without ES6 goodies:

```
scene.children.slice().forEach(function(obj) { scene.remove(obj); })
```

Comment: hm, but how to remove an exact childrens? for some reasons this does not work for me scene.children[2].children.forEach(i=>scene.remove(i)) and this does not work too scene.remove(scene.getObjectByName("earth_marker"))

Answer (score 2):

You should use !== instead of != (its a bit faster). Did you tried to step through your loop and check scene children after that? Maybe you added some boxes to the plane as childs which will not be deleted by this loop.

Comment: Good idea. Thats was not the problem, but thank you anyway for the idea Mr @Sebastian Sachtleben. Greetings